# Deserializing json with GSON in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have Json

```
{"0x3b198e26e473b8fab2085b37978e36c9de5d7f68":{"usd":541.56},"0x54523d5fb56803bac758e8b10b321748a77ae9e9":{"usd":0.059097},"0x330540a9d998442dcbc396165d3ddc5052077bb1":{"usd":1.649e-09}}
```

Next, I am using gson trying to convert json to price object

```
        RequestEntity requestEntity = new RequestEntity(requestHeaders, HttpMethod.valueOf("GET"), uri);
        restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
        String response = responseEntity.getBody();
        System.out.println(response);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Price price = gson.fromJson(response, Price.class);
```

**Price.java**

```
  public class Price {
        private Wallet wallet;
        private Wallet token;
        private Wallet contract;
    
        public Wallet getWallet() {
            return wallet;
        }
    
        public void setWallet(Wallet wallet) {
            this.wallet = wallet;
        }
    
        public Wallet getToken() {
            return token;
        }
    
        public void setToken(Wallet token) {
            this.token = token;
        }
    
        public Wallet getContract() {
            return contract;
        }
    
        public void setContract(Wallet contract) {
            this.contract = contract;
        }
    }
```

**Wallet.java**

```
public class Wallet {
    private Currencies currencies;

    public Currencies getCurrencies() {
        return currencies;
    }

    public void setCurrencies(Currencies currencies) {
        this.currencies = currencies;
    }
}
```

**Currencies.java**

```
public class Currencies {
    String currency;
    Integer value;

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I need to name the class fields "**0x3b198e26e473b8fab2085b37978e36c9de5d7f68**", "**0x54523d5fb56803bac758e8b10b321748a77ae9e9**" and "**0x330540a9d998442dcbc396165d3dbb150**"? If so, these are not valid names.

Otherwise I get null when calling

```
        System.out.println(price.getWallet());
```

Comment: Gson should support custom names with annotations. Search on google. Maybe this https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html.

Comment: Are those names hardcodeable? I don't think so. Have you heard of `java.util.Map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you can utilize custom deserializers here

register them for Gson like this:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBldr = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBldr.registerTypeAdapter(Price.class, new PriceCustomDeserializer());
gsonBldr.registerTypeAdapter(Wallet.class, new WalletCustomDeserializer());
gsonBldr.registerTypeAdapter(Currencies.class, new CurrenciesCustomDeserializer());
```

and deserializers implementation:

```
public class PriceCustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Price> {

    @Override
    public Price deserialize
      (JsonElement jElement, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) 
      throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jObject = jElement.getAsJsonObject();
        //parse 3 values (without names) from json by order 
    }
}

//add remaining 2 deserializers
```